# Using a Go Template var inside of a `{{ template }}`

Tags: go, go-templates, go-html-template

In Go we can create a variable easily enough with

```
{{- if .Bool.Var -}}
  {{ $MyVar := "val" }}
{{- end -}}
```

We can even create shared snippets easily enough

```
{{- define "val" -}}
  <p>Some shared template data</p>
{{- end -}}
```

***My question*** is, how do we go about using `$MyVar` as a text value for `{{template}}` so that we can do something like `{{template $MyVar}}`, without causing an error, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pure [Go `text/template` language](https://godoc.org/text/template) (which is not Go *per se* but something different which happens to be implemented in Go) this isn't possible; the `{{template}}` invocation takes a literal string name.

One of the most prominent users of this language is the Kubernetes [Helm](https://helm.sh) deployment manager.  That includes several extensions to the template language.  One of those is an [`include` template function](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide#the-include-function) that can take any value as the name of the template, and produces a string rather than immediately outputting the template contents (you can include it in a pipeline, which you can't with `template`).  So specifically in a [kubernetes-helm](/questions/tagged/kubernetes-helm) YAML file, you could

```
{{ include $MyVar }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something close to what they do, and created a `template.FuncMap` with an include tag that takes the variable and context, so I can grab that define and pass it back.  Not very ideal but it works.